# How to get DropDown menu to write to JavaScript Cookie

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I need help making the drop-down menu work with cookies. Thanks in advance for your help. I need to understand how Cookies work with drop-downs, radio button select lists and how to make them display the results. Here is the JavaScript and HTML for page one and page two. If there is an easier way to do this with HTML5 LocalStorage please explain. I tried Local Storage and it would not work on IE or Opera older browsers. So instead of fallback code, I just went with JS Cookies.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getCookie(name){var re=new RegExp(name+"=([^;]+)");var      value=re.exec(document.cookie);return(value!=null)?unescape(value[1]):null;}

var today=new Date();var expiry=new Date(today.getTime()+30*24*3600*1000);var    expired=new Date(today.getTime()-24*3600*1000);
var cusineChoice = document.getElementByName("CAT_Custom_307514");
function setCookie(name,value){document.cookie=name+"="+escape(value)+"; path=/;     expires="+expiry.toGMTString();}

function deleteCookie(name){document.cookie=name+"=null; path=/; expires="+expired.toGMTString();}
function storeValues(form)
{setCookie("FullAddress",form.FullAddress.value);setCookie("Postcode_18870",form.Postcode_18870.value);setCookie("field3",form.field3.value);setCookie("field4",form.field4.value);setCookie("CAT_Custom_307514",form.CAT_Custom_307514.options[form.CAT_Custom_307514.selectedIndex].value);return true;}
</script>

<form name="catcustomcontentform85290" method="post" onSubmit="return checkWholeForm85290(this)&& storeValues(this);" action="/Default.aspx?CCID=18870&amp;FID=112543&amp;ExcludeBoolFalse=True&amp;ID=/chowsquad-results">


    <div class="input_sign_home full_address_search">
     <label class="infieldlabel" for="FullAddress">
     Street Address, City, State
     <span class="req">*</span>
     </label>
     <br>
<input id="FullAddress" class="cat_textbox signup_input_main" type="text"     name="FullAddress" maxlength="255">
</div>



        <div class="input_sign_home zip_search1">

            <label for="Postcode_18870" class="infieldlabel">Zipcode*</label><br />
            <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="Postcode_18870" id="Postcode_18870" class="cat_textbox signup_input_main" />
       <div class="hidden">
           <label for="Distance_18870">Distance</label><br />
            <select name="Distance_18870" id="Distance_18870" class="cat_dropdown">
            <option value="5">5 miles</option>
            <option value="10">10 miles</option>
            <option value="20">20 miles</option>
            <option value="50">50 miles</option>
            <option value="100">100 miles</option>
            </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="input_sign_home cuisine_search1">
        <div class="input_sign_home">


        <label class="hidden_label" for="CAT_Custom_134967">Choose Your Chow!</label></div>
        <div class="title_select_vendor rest_country">
            <select name="CAT_Custom_307514" id="CAT_Custom_307514" class="cat_dropdown selectv">
             <option value="">Choose Your Chow!</option>
            <option value="*">-- All --</option>
            <option value="American">American</option>
            <option value="BBQ">BBQ</option>
            <option value="Chinese">Chinese</option>
            <option value="Deli">Deli</option>
            <option value="Grocery Stores">Grocery Stores</option>
            <option value="Italian">Italian</option>
            <option value="Jamaican">Jamaican</option>
            <option value="Japanese">Japanese</option>
            <option value="Indian">Indian</option>
            <option value="Mexican">Mexican</option>
            <option value="Middle Eastern">Middle Eastern</option>
            <option value="Pizza">Pizza</option>
            <option value="Seafood">Seafood</option>
            <option value="Sushi">Sushi</option>
            <option value="Tex-Mex">Tex-Mex</option>
            <option value="Thai">Thai</option>
            <option value="Vegetarian">Vegetarian</option>
            <option value="Vietnamese">Vietnamese</option>
            <option value="----OTHER RESTAURANTS ----">----OTHER RESTAURANTS ----</option>
            <option value="African">African</option>
            <option value="Argentinian">Argentinian</option>
            <option value="Austrian">Austrian</option>
            <option value="Bagels">Bagels</option>
            <option value="Belgian">Belgian</option>
            <option value="Brazilian">Brazilian</option>
            <option value="Breakfast">Breakfast</option>
            <option value="Brunch">Brunch</option>
            <option value="Burgers">Burgers</option>
            <option value="Cajun and Creole">Cajun and Creole</option>
            <option value="Californian Cuisine">Californian Cuisine</option>
            <option value="Cambodian">Cambodian</option>
            <option value="Caribbean">Caribbean</option>
            <option value="Cheesesteaks">Cheesesteaks</option>
            <option value="Costa Rican">Costa Rican</option>
            <option value="Crepes">Crepes</option>
            <option value="Cuban">Cuban</option>
            <option value="Dessert">Dessert</option>
            <option value="Dim Sum and Dumplings">Dim Sum and Dumplings</option>
            <option value="Diner">Diner</option>
            <option value="English">English</option>
            <option value="Filipino">Filipino</option>
            <option value="French">French</option>
            <option value="German">German</option>
            <option value="Gluten Free">Gluten Free</option>
            <option value="Greek">Greek</option>
            <option value="Haitian">Haitian</option>
            <option value="Halal">Halal</option>
            <option value="Hawaiian">Hawaiian</option>
            <option value="Healthy">Healthy</option>
            <option value="Hot Dogs">Hot Dogs</option>
            <option value="Indonesian">Indonesian</option>
            <option value="Irish">Irish</option>
            <option value="Korean">Korean</option>
            <option value="Kosher">Kosher</option>
            <option value="Latin American">Latin American</option>
            <option value="Lebanese">Lebanese</option>
            <option value="Malaysian">Malaysian</option>
            <option value="Mediterranean">Mediterranean</option>
            <option value="Moroccan">Moroccan</option>
            <option value="Noodle Shops">Noodle Shops</option>
            <option value="Organic">Organic</option>
            <option value="Peruvian">Peruvian</option>
            <option value="Polish">Polish</option>
            <option value="Portuguese">Portuguese</option>
            <option value="Russian">Russian</option>
            <option value="Salads">Salads</option>
            <option value="Sandwiches and Wraps">Sandwiches and Wraps</option>
            <option value="Scandinavian">Scandinavian</option>
            <option value="Smoothies and Shakes">Smoothies and Shakes</option>
            <option value="Soups">Soups</option>
            <option value="Southern and Soul">Southern and Soul</option>
            <option value="Spanish and Tapas">Spanish and Tapas</option>
            <option value="Sri Lankan">Sri Lankan</option>
            <option value="Steakhouse">Steakhouse</option>
            <option value="Taiwanese">Taiwanese</option>
            <option value="Turkish">Turkish</option>
            <option value="Vegan">Vegan</option>
            <option value="Venezuelan">Venezuelan</option>
            <option value="Wings">Wings</option>
            </select>


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="search_btn_1">
        <input id="find_resta_btn" class="cat_button search_rest_1" type="image" src="/images/search_restaurant_home_off.png" value="Find Your Favorite Restaurant!" />
        </div>
        <div class="edge_iFrame_rest_btn">
        <iframe class="animate" width="650" height="118" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="http://www.chowsquad.com/animate/ChowSquad_search_ani/index.html" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="advanced_search_link">
        <a href="/advanced-search">Advanced Search</a></div>
    </form>
```

Here is the code on the corresponding page.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">     // Original JavaScript code by Chirp Internet:     www.chirp.com.au // Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header. 

function getCookie(name) { var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)"); var value = re.exec(document.cookie); return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null; } </script>
<p><span class="count_no"> </span>    restaurants serving <span id="street_address">     <script type="text/javascript"> document.write(getCookie("FullAddress")); </script> </span> <span id="zipContainer"><script type="text/javascript">  document.write(getCookie("Postcode_18870")); </script> </span><span><script type="text/javascript"> document.write(getCookie("CAT_Custom_307514")); </script></span></p>
```

Comment: Just for anyone to fiddle with... http://jsfiddle.net/txggM/

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
window.onload=function() {   
 var spanId=["street_address","zip_container"];
 var field=["FullAddress","...."];
 for (var i=0;i<field.length;i++) {
   document.getElementById(spanId[i]).innerHTML=getCookie(field[i]) || "";
 }
}
```